# How to Next and Prevous Navigation Buttons on the end of the page with custom image Using Wp Post Navigation Plugin

Tags: posts, navigation, links, next

I am New to Wordpress and Don't know Coding hecnce on my website i have two section one for blog and other is episodes with seperate catageory and to navigate between the post in same catageory, So Iam Using This Plugin Called Wp Post Navigation by Anas Mir.It me Working Fine For me for the cattageoris in which Iam i Want to Navigate in Episode Posts as Ihave Changed the Imgae of Previous and Next Episode Button with Text as Previous Episode and Next Episode hence it is good for the Epsiodes Posts at Bottom of Every Post in EPisodes Catageory But Their Is No Option for Excluding the Catageories(News Blog) in which i don't want show these buttons(Previous Episode and Next Episode Button) and No option to Resize the buttons also,I contacted the Developer but no response hence i'am here please help friends this is the code of Plugin is below or Is there any other way to do this.
these are the option its shows in plug in setting:[image: Optins available in plugin Setting]
[image: Optins available in plugin Setting]

```
/*
Plugin Name: WP Post Navigation
Version: 1.2.4
Description: Show Previous and Next Post Links at Posts.
Author: Anas Mir
Author URI: http://sharp-coders.com/author/anasmir
Plugin URI: http://sharp-coders.com/wp-post-navigation
*/

/*Check Version*/
global $wp_version;
$exit_msg="WP Requires Latest version, Your version is old";
if(version_compare($wp_version, "3.0", "<"))
{
    exit($exit_msg);
}

if(!class_exists('WPPostNavigation')):
    class WPPostNavigation{
        private $config = array('hasImage'=>'','prePost'=>'','nextPost'=>'','is_reversed'=>false,'is_active'=>false);
        function load_settings()
        {
            $options = $this->get_wp_post_navigation_options();
            $navi = $options['nav_within_cat'] == "1"? true: false;
            $next_post = get_next_post($navi);
            $pre_post = get_previous_post($navi);
            if($options['navi_img'] != "1")
            {
                if($options['is_custom'] != "1"){
                    $pre_navigation = $pre_post->ID!=""?'<a href="'. get_permalink($pre_post->ID).'">'.$pre_post->post_title.'</a>':'';
                    $next_navigation = $next_post->ID!=""?'<a href="'. get_permalink($next_post->ID).'">'.$next_post->post_title.'</a>':'';
                }else{
                    $pre_navigation = $pre_post->ID!=""?'<a href="'. get_permalink($pre_post->ID).'">'.$options['custom_pre'].'</a>':'';

                    $next_navigation = $next_post->ID!=""?'<a href="'. get_permalink($next_post->ID).'">'.$options['custom_next'].'</a>':'';
                }

            }else{
                $pre_navigation = $pre_post->ID!=""?'<a href="'. get_permalink($pre_post->ID).'"><img src="'.$options['pre_img_link'].'" /></a>':'';
                $next_navigation = $next_post->ID!=""?'<a href="'. get_permalink($next_post->ID).'"><img src="'.$options['next_img_link'].'" /></a>':'';
            }
            $img = $options['navi_img'] == "1"? "-1": '';
            $this->config["is_reversed"] = $options['is_reversed'];
            $this->config["hasImage"] = $img;
            $nex = ($this->config["is_reversed"] == "1")?$next_navigation:$pre_navigation;
            $pre = ($this->config["is_reversed"] == "1")?$pre_navigation:$next_navigation;
            $this->config["prePost"] = $pre;
            $this->config["nextPost"] = $nex;
            $this->config["is_active"] = $options['is_active'];
            $this->config["position"] = $options['position'];
        }
        function WP_Pre_Next_Navigation($content)
        {
            global $post;
            $this->load_settings();
            if($this->config["is_active"] == "1"){
                if(is_single()){
                    switch($this->config["position"]){
                            case "both":
                                return '<div class="wp-post-navigation">
                                       <div class="wp-post-navigation-pre'.$this->config["hasImage"].'">
                                       '.$this->config["prePost"].'
                                       </div>
                                       <div class="wp-post-navigation-next'.$this->config["hasImage"].'">
                                       '.$this->config["nextPost"].'
                                       </div>
                                    </div>'.$content.'<div class="wp-post-navigation">
                                       <div class="wp-post-navigation-pre'.$this->config["hasImage"].'">
                                       '.$this->config["prePost"].'
                                       </div>
                                       <div class="wp-post-navigation-next'.$this->config["hasImage"].'">
                                       '.$this->config["nextPost"].'
                                       </div>
                                    </div>';
                                break;
                            case "top":
                                    return '<div class="wp-post-navigation">
                                       <div class="wp-post-navigation-pre'.$this->config["hasImage"].'">
                                       '.$this->config["prePost"].'
                                       </div>
                                       <div class="wp-post-navigation-next'.$this->config["hasImage"].'">
                                       '.$this->config["nextPost"].'
                                       </div>
                                    </div>'.$content;
                                break;
                            case "bottom":
                                return $content.'<div class="wp-post-navigation">
                                       <div class="wp-post-navigation-pre'.$this->config["hasImage"].'">
                                       '.$this->config["prePost"].'
                                       </div>
                                       <div class="wp-post-navigation-next'.$this->config["hasImage"].'">
                                       '.$this->config["nextPost"].'
                                       </div>
                                    </div>';
                                break;
                            default:
                                return $content;
                                break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return $content;
        }
        function WP_Custom_Post_Navigation()
        {
            if(is_single())
            {
                return '<div class="wp-post-navigation">
                           <div class="wp-post-navigation-pre'.$this->config["hasImage"].'" >
                           '.$this->config["prePost"].'
                           </div>
                           <div class="wp-post-navigation-next'.$this->config["hasImage"].'">
                           '.$this->config["nextPost"].'
                           </div>
                        </div>';
            }
        }
        function handle_wp_post_navigation_options()
        {
            $settings = $this->get_wp_post_navigation_options();
            if (isset($_POST['submitted']))
            {
                //check security
                check_admin_referer('wp-post-navigation-by-sharp-coders');
                $settings['nav_within_cat'] = isset($_POST['nav_within_cat'])? "1" : "0" ;
                $settings['is_active'] = isset($_POST['is_active'])? "1" : "0" ;
                $settings['is_reversed'] = isset($_POST['is_reversed'])? "1" : "0" ;
                $settings['position'] = isset($_POST['position'])? $_POST['position'] : "bottom" ;
                $settings['style'] = isset($_POST['style_css'])? $_POST['style_css'] : "" ;
                $settings['is_custom'] = isset($_POST['is_custom'])? "1" : "0" ;
                $settings['custom_pre'] = isset($_POST['custom_pre'])? $_POST['custom_pre'] : "" ;
                $settings['custom_next'] = isset($_POST['custom_next'])? $_POST['custom_next'] : "" ;
                $settings['navi_img'] = isset($_POST['navi_img'])? "1" : "0" ;
                $settings['pre_img_link'] = isset($_POST['pre_img_link'])? $_POST['pre_img_link'] : "" ;
                $settings['next_img_link'] = isset($_POST['next_img_link'])? $_POST['next_img_link'] : "" ;

                update_option("wp_post_navigation_options", serialize($settings));
                echo '<div class="updated fade"><p>Setting Updated!</p></div>';
            }
            $action_url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
            include 'wp-post-navigation-admin-options.php';
        }

        function get_wp_post_navigation_options()
        {
            $options = unserialize(get_option("wp_post_navigation_options"));
            return $options;
        }
        function WP_Post_Navigation_install()
        {
            $options = $this->get_wp_post_navigation_options();
            $options = array(
                'is_active' => (isset($options) && is_array($options) && isset($options["is_active"]))?$options["is_active"]:'1',
                'is_reversed' => (isset($options) && is_array($options) && isset($options["is_reversed"]))?$options["is_reversed"]:'0',
                'position' => (isset($options) && is_array($options) && isset($options["position"]))?$options["position"]:'bottom',
                'nav_within_cat' => (isset($options) && is_array($options) && isset($options["nav_within_cat"]))?$options["nav_within_cat"]:'1',
                'style' => (isset($options) && is_array($options) && isset($options["style"]))?$options["style"]:'text-decoration: none;
font:bold 16px sans-serif, arial;
color: #666;',
                'is_custom' => (isset($options) && is_array($options) && isset($options["is_custom"]))?$options["is_custom"]:'0',
                'custom_pre' => (isset($options) && is_array($options) && isset($options["custom_pre"]))?$options["custom_pre"]:'Previous Post',
                'custom_next' => (isset($options) && is_array($options) && isset($options["custom_next"]))?$options["custom_next"]:'Next Post',
                'navi_img' => (isset($options) && is_array($options) && isset($options["navi_img"]))?$options["navi_img"]:'0',
                'pre_img_link' => (isset($options) && is_array($options) && isset($options["pre_img_link"]))?$options["pre_img_link"]:'',
                'next_img_link' => (isset($options) && is_array($options) && isset($options["next_img_link"]))?$options["next_img_link"]:'',

            );
            add_option("wp_post_navigation_options", serialize($options));
        }
        function wp_admin_menu()
        {
            add_options_page('WP Post Navigation', 'WP Post Navigation', 10, basename(__FILE__), array(&$this, 'handle_wp_post_navigation_options'));
        }

        function wp_post_navigation_stylesheet() {
            wp_register_style( 'wp-post-navigation-style', plugins_url('style.css', __FILE__) );
            wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-post-navigation-style' );
        }
        function wp_post_navigation_HeadAction()
        {
            $settings = $this->get_wp_post_navigation_options();
            echo '<style type="text/css">
                    .wp-post-navigation a{
                    '.$settings['style'].'
                    }
                 </style>';
        }
    }
else:
    exit('WPPostNavigation Already Exists');
endif;

$WPPostNavigation = new WPPostNavigation();
if(isset($WPPostNavigation)){
    register_activation_hook(__FILE__, array(&$WPPostNavigation, 'WP_Post_Navigation_install'));
    add_filter('wp_head', array(&$WPPostNavigation, 'wp_post_navigation_HeadAction'));
    add_filter('the_content', array(&$WPPostNavigation, 'WP_Pre_Next_Navigation'));
    add_action('admin_menu', array(&$WPPostNavigation, 'wp_admin_menu'));
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array(&$WPPostNavigation, 'wp_post_navigation_stylesheet'));
    add_shortcode('WPNextPrevious', array(&$WPPostNavigation, 'WP_Custom_Post_Navigation'));
}


?>
```